# SSL: can the secret key be sniffed before the actual encryption begins?

Tags: ssl, openssl, sniffing

I was looking into SSL and some of the steps that are involved to set up an encrypted connection between a server and a client computer.

I understand that a server key and certificate is sent to the browser, and that a secret code is being calculated, like they say in the following video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iQsKdtjwtYI

around 5:22, they talk about a master secret code that is being calculated to start talking in an encrypted way.

My question now is: before the connection is actually encrypted (the handshake phase), all communication between the server and the client can be sniffed by a packet sniffer. Isn't it then possible to sniff the encryption key or other data that is used to set up a secure connection?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange

Answer (score 3):

From the [Wikipedia summary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Simple_TLS_handshake), I think the key part you're interested in is:

> The client responds with a ClientKeyExchange message, which may
>   contain a PreMasterSecret, public key, or nothing. (Again, this
>   depends on the selected cipher.) This PreMasterSecret is encrypted
>   using the public key of the server certificate.

This is why the public key is so important.  If you use the wrong public key, you're vulnerable to man in middle attacks.

Witness the justified worry whenever bogus SSL certificate issues (e.g. [DigiNotar](http://www.metafilter.com/106990/DigiNotar-SSL-certificate-compromise)).

Comment: thank you, but also here I have the same questions: isn't it possible for a sniffer to respond with a ClientKeyExchange message, just like the browser does? I mean, all info that's sent from and to the browser is just sniffable since there is no SSL connections during the handshake process yet?

Comment: @Jorre, as stated the below, an attacker can certainly send an encrypted PreMasterSecret to the authentic server (they're a client too!).  But the attacker can not *decrypt* a PreMasterSecret sent by the authentic client (which should be encrypted with the real public key as determined from the cert), so the man in the middle attack fails.

Answer (score 2):

The secret key itself isn't transmitted at all, so it can't be sniffed. It is computed independently at both ends. The materials it is computed from is called a PreMasterSecret which is encrypted with the public key of the server certificate. So unless the server's private key has been compromised the secret key can be neither sniffed nor calculated independently.

Comment: Thanks. So based on the PreMasterSecret a client and server start talking in an encrypted way? Can't a sniffer sniff the PreMasterSecret then and also generate its own secret key, just like a browser does with the same info it gets from the server?

Comment: @Jorre not unless he has the private key of the server to decrypt it with, see above.

Comment: thanks EJP, but I'm not really sure I get why a browser can set up a secure connection with the server and a sniffer app can't with exactly the same info that a browser and server send to eachother before setting up the encrypted connection. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @Jorre, 2 things.  1. The sniffer doesn't have the server's private key.  2.  The real client doesn't trust (unless there's a a SSL certificate compromise) the sniffer's public key.

Comment: Hi Matthew, the browser doens't have the server's private key either. So am I correct that you are saying that any client/browser/sniffer that makes a connection with a server has it's own public key and that all these connections are talking in another secret encrypted way with the server? The sniffer is then taling in another code in comparison with the browser?

Comment: @BobAnonymous suggests "I think he's saying that the CLIENT generates the PreMasterKey, and then encrypts it with the SERVER public key, which only the SERVER can decrypt, and then they use that to build the MasterKey, is that correct?"