# Ways to secure Server communication

Tags: node.js, security

I have game, and server on node.js.
Client->serwer is VIA POST & GET.

Now I have client->server request:
Request type POST.
/login
{ privateVariable: "someVariable" }

After that, serwer is generating public/private key, sending public to client. And from this moment,
all requests client->server have to be encrypted.

For example:
Request type POST.
/addPoints
{ userID: "someID", cryptedJSON: "some crypted JSON with add points request" }

But my problem is:
When hacker will know privateVariable he/she will just use it to login and recieive public key. From this moment he/she can hack, using recievied variable.

Do you know any better securing options?

Comment: Use HTTPS. That way you don't have to implement a secure connection yourself.

Comment: I want to secure requests, to not be hacked.

Comment: There's no simple answer to this: you just have to make your server un-hackable by normal means. **Refuse** to perform actions that are not valid in the user's context. **Do not expose** actions like "add points": the server must know when to do that

Comment: So if customer told me "offline game that will update scoreboard on connect". I should tell him: "there is no way to secure it" Right?
Because i have requests like:
serveraddress/updateScore data: { user_id: "someId", token: "someToken", points: 100 } And it's not totaly possible to secure it right? Everyone can just scan packet and see requests.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to secure the connection between the client and the server is using HTTPS.

The secure HTTP communication relies on the [SSL/TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) protocol. Any other way can be hacked easily by sniffing the data between the user and the server (Man in the middle attack).

See this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8287583/ssl-can-the-secret-key-be-sniffed-before-the-actual-encryption-begins) to understand why the HTTPS cannot be sniffed.

Comment: Yes. But if user is hacker, he can use his own HTTPS connection that was established to make unathorized CURL requests right?

Comment: The HTTPS only protects the communication between the client and the server in the manner that a third party (hacker) won't be able to understand the messages and misuse the secured information. If you want to limit your users from performing some actions, encrypting their messages has nothing to do with it.